# MVC 6 / Web API Routing Template Issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

In my controller, I have the following method:

```
[HttpGet("SimulateLogin/{userName}/{password}")]

public async Task<IActionResult> SimulateLogin(string userName, string password)
{
  ...
}
```

If I issue a call to the following URL:

*BaseUrl*/SimulateLogin/*userName*/*password*

I get a valid (200 / OK) response back.

If I usse a call to the following URL:

*BaseUrl*/SimulateLogin/?userName=*userName*&password=*password*

I get an invalid (404 / Not Found) response back.

What is the difference?  Why does the first work but not the second.  I know that both formats work in previous versions of MVC / Web API.

Comment: FYI in case it's not only for testing. You should not put the password in the url

Comment: Yes, this is for testing purposes only.  The key point is that it doesn't matter what parameters I choose to pass along in the URL, the condition described will remain.

Comment: Maybe you need to mark them as optional for the query string to be accepted as well? If I remember correctly it was defined like `"SimulateLogin/{userName?}/{password?}"`

Comment: @DanielJ.G. - You suggestion worked.  I will most certainly need to brush up on the route template syntax.  What was most confusing is that I did not need to do this in previous versions of MVC / Web API.  Granted, we are still in a beta release so this may be something that will change.  At any rate, if you would like to make your comment an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Yeah, its hard to know which things changed and which ones didn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add those parameters as optional parameters in your template:

```
[HttpGet("SimulateLogin/{userName?}/{password?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SimulateLogin(string userName, string password)
{
  ...
}
```

[This post](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing) had a nice overview of the updated routing features in ASP 5/MVC 6, but I wouldn't be surprised if things change a bit before the 1.0 release.